# How to set Passwordless login on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, login, password

On Ubuntu 16.04 I used passwordless login. After upgrading to 18.04 this didn't work any more.

To be clear, my question is about passwordless login, not autologin (logging automatically in to a certain account on start-up.)

1) Ubuntu Settings

In the Ubuntu settings window there is no checkbox for a passwordless login. In prior versions it said

```
"Don't ask for password on login"
```

[Image: Ubuntu Settings > Details > Users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcVJu.png)

2) The "Users Administration Tool"

The "Users Administration Tool" shows the setting "Password: Not asked on login".
[Image: Users Administration Tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fif4p.png)

3) Command Line

On the command line the following information is obtained:

```
pwp@my-ubuntu-1:~$ cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager 
/usr/sbin/gdm3


pwp@my-ubuntu-1:~$ getent group nopasswdlogin 
nopasswdlogin:x:119:pwp,mypartner
```

Answer (score 1):

[This works,](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GDM#Passwordless_login) but I don't know if it's safe.

> If you want to bypass the password prompt in GDM then simply add the following line on the first line of `/etc/pam.d/gdm-password`:
>
> ```
> auth sufficient pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup nopasswdlogin
> ```
>
> Then, add the group `nopasswdlogin` to your system.
>
> Now, add your user to the `nopasswdlogin` group and you will only have to click on your username to login.

I don't know if it's safe, because the `sufficient` control bypasses the other rules that follow, including SELinux session rules, and I don't understand what any of that stuff does.